# Initial git push into freshly created repo on GitLab rejected

Tags: git, gitlab

In GitLab I created a new repo from scratch (without initializing it with a README), then I ran these commands on my local machine to init and push

```
git init -b main
git add . && git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:my-repo/myapp.git
git remote -v
```

In the next step I tried to push by `git push -u origin main`, but this is rejected:

> ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first) error: failed to push
> some refs to 'gitlab.com:alexander.brehm/haraldpopp.de.git
> hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you
> do hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another
> repository pushing hint: to the same ref. You may want to first
> integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before
> pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push
> --help' for details.

According to the hints, I tried `git pull`, but this results in

```
 * [new branch]      main       -> origin/main
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.
    git pull  
If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:
    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branch main
```

So I did a `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main`, but this results in

```
hint: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
hint: discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
hint: commands sometime before your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
```

I don't know, what to do. I never had this issue before.

EDIT:
Results of further tests:

SSH is working: `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`

Status of local and remote:

```
$ git status
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@gitlab.com:my/app.git
  Push  URL: git@gitlab.com:my/app.git
  HEAD branch: main
  Remote branch:
    main new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    main pushes to main (local out of date)
```

Comment: `git pull --rebase origin main`

Comment: Or does `git push -u origin main` work now?

Comment: Also do what the hint said: say `git config pull.rebase false`

Comment: I did `git config pull.rebase false`, `git pull --rebase origin main`and then `git push -u origin main` but it is still rejected.

Comment: Interesting. Rejected with what message? Is it still saying "the remote contains work that you do  not have locally"?

Comment: Also did you configure SSH at GitLab?

Comment: I configured SSH under https://gitlab.com/-/profile/keys. `git pull --rebase origin main` resultes in message "already up to date", while `git push -u origin main` resulted in `[rejected] main -> main (non-fast-forward)`.

Comment: Makes no sense. What about `git push --force-with-lease origin main`?

Comment: It is almost as if you were not on `main`. What does `git status` say? What does `git remote show origin` say?

Comment: I added both status messages at the end of my question.

Comment: OK so the implication is that you should now say `git fetch origin`. — Also I'm curious as to what version of Git you're using.

Comment: I'm using git 2.32.0 (Apple Git-132). I ended up by deleting the repo on gitLab and creating it by local command `git push --all --set-upstream git@gitlab.com:my.name/app.git` … in this way, everything is working.

Comment: Cool! Then either give that as an Answer to your own question, or else delete the question. Thanks. (Maybe this is some weird GitLab behavior.)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out why the issue occured; maybe it's because when manually generating a repo in gitLab, then a file .gitlab-ci.yml is created automatically.

Finally I ended up by deleting the repo on gitLab and creating it from scratch by local command `git push --all --set-upstream git@gitlab.com:my.name/app.git` In this way, everything is working.

Answer (score -1):

You should do `git pull origin main` then check everything in your code looks as it should and the do your `git push origin main` command.

Comment: `git pull origin main && git push origin main` resulted in `[rejected] main -> main (non-fast-forward)`